# when executing program, extra input command causes logical errors java

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to execute a program called AverageRainfall. Most of the input works well (my while statement at the beginning is fine), but there are multiple months under the variable monthRain, and the while statement for monthRain is not functioning with the various months, only the initial input command, which is serving no purpose.

ETA: Posting entire code for testing

```
  import java.util.Scanner; //for Scanner class

  public class AverageRainfall
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     final int NUM_MONTHS = 12;     //Months per year
     int years;                     //Number of years
     double monthRain;                  //Rain for a month
     double totalRain = 0;              //Rainfall accumulator
     double average;                    //Average rainfall

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

     {
     System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
     years = keyboard.nextInt();

     while (years < 1)
        {
        System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
        years = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
     }

      { 
         System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");
         monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();

         for(int y = 1; y <= years; y++){

           for(int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++){

       System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");
       monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
       }
       }
       while (monthRain < 0)
      {
         System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 0 or greater: ");
         monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();
      }
      }  

       {
        totalRain += monthRain;

        average = totalRain / (years * NUM_MONTHS);

        System.out.println("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS) );
        System.out.println("Total rainfall: " + totalRain + " inches");
        System.out.println("Average monthly rainfall: " + average + " inches");
       }
    }
}
```

This is the entire code.

Comment: can u post the whole code so I can test it?

Comment: yes post the complete code. Difficult to guess. But I think whats happening is totalRain += monthRain; is not in loop and thats the reason all months are not considered

Comment: @Kognizant how would I go about putting it in the loop?

Comment: actually Ziad has already shown how to put it inside the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using unnecessary braces. Moreover, some logical flaws were also present in your code. I have fixed your code. Please refer the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; //for Scanner class

public class AverageRainfall {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int NUM_MONTHS = 12; // Months per year
    int years; // Number of years
    double monthRain=0; // Rain for a month
    double totalRain = 0; // Rainfall accumulator
    double average; // Average rainfall

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the number of years: ");
    years = keyboard.nextInt();

    while (years < 1) {
        System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 1 or greater: ");
        years = keyboard.nextInt();

    }


    System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");
    for (int y = 1; y <= years; y++) {

        for (int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++) {

            System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");
            monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();

            while (monthRain < 0) {
                System.out.print("Invalid. Enter 0 or greater: ");
                monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            totalRain += monthRain;
        }   
    }   





    average = totalRain / (years * NUM_MONTHS);

    System.out.println("\nNumber of months: " + (years * NUM_MONTHS));
    System.out.println("Total rainfall: " + totalRain + " inches");
    System.out.println("Average monthly rainfall: " + average
                + " inches");

 }
}
```

Comment: There was a brace missing in the final code, but that was taken care of when I integrated it. Thank you very much, that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add to the total of Rain each time the user inputs a month rain. Then you can do the average once he finishes inputting data.

`import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    double monthRain=0;
    double totalRain=0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int years = 1;
    int NUM_MONTHS = 12;
    System.out.println("Enter the rainfall, in inches, for each month. ");
    for(int y = 1; y <= years; y++){
        for(int m = 1; m <= NUM_MONTHS; m++){

            System.out.print("Year" + y + "month" + m + ": ");
            monthRain = keyboard.nextDouble(); 
            totalRain+=monthRain;
        }
    }
    int totalMonth = years*NUM_MONTHS;
    System.out.println("\nNumber of months: " + totalMonth );
    System.out.println("Total Rain: "+totalRain+" inches");
    double average = totalRain / totalMonth;
    System.out.println("Average monthly rainfall: " + average + " inches");

}
```

}
`

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem when using your code, it says it only rained one inch in 2 years.

Comment: I fixed something in the System.out.println, the first one should be "Total Rain". What input are you using?

Comment: If you execute the code now and input 1 for all months, you will get Total rain = 12, and average rain = 1

Comment: Sorry that was stupid I was using 2 years and randomizing the numbers. For my assignment the years and rainfall have to be variable, in that any amount of years over 1 is acceptable and any amount of rainfall greater than 0 is acceptable.

Comment: Run my code. The program expects the user to input rain quantity for 12 months. Now input 1 for month1year1, 1 for month2year1, and same for the rest 10 months. As a result the total rain is 12 since you inputted 1*12 and average rain is the total/num_of_month which is 12/12 = 1. So your average rain per month is 1 inch which is correct.

Comment: I ran your code and it does work beautifully. However I need it to work for more than one year.

Comment: You can change the year and it will still work. Just integrate my code with your code where the user inputs the number of years.

Comment: That worked quite well once I actually put it all together. sorry I was being dense

Comment: You're welcome. That is because I started testing it before you posted the whole code. You said my solution worked and now you upvoted the other solution that was later posted.